# Hyperledger fabric peer chaincode instantiate timeout

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

So I'm at the "try to instantiate chain code across my consortium stage".
I installed it on all my peers - 200s across the board.

When I get to this piece it does a little then hangs and times out

```
=====================================================================================================
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer:7050 --tls true --cafile /crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/orderer.com/orderers/orderer.orderer.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.orderer.com-cert.pem -C aac -n mycc -v 1.0 
-c '{"Args":["init","a", "100", "b","200"]}' -P "OR ('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member','Org3MSP.member')"
=====================================================================================================
2017-10-28 02:02:56.853 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2017-10-28 02:02:56.853 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2017-10-28 02:02:56.867 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003 Using default escc
2017-10-28 02:02:56.868 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 004 Using default vscc
2017-10-28 02:02:56.869 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 005 Sign: plaintext: 0A9D070A7508031A0C08D0CACFCF0510...30300A000A04657363630A0476736363 
2017-10-28 02:02:56.869 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 006 Sign: digest: EDDBC0833DC1815A04B56C17D7D7DC6CAE967A8BA1C5082668234325F325F1C1 
Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Timeout expired while starting chaincode mycc:1.0(networkid:dev,peerid:peer0.org1.com,tx:dcd9c8c334467ee867fdd82fdbbec483532281364b20fda1fcd1298a66a836b3)
```

The peer log ends like this:

```
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:56.896 UTC [shim] sendChannel -> DEBU 540 [dcd9c8c3]after send
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:56.896 UTC [shim] afterResponse -> DEBU 541 [dcd9c8c3]Received RESPONSE, communicated (state:ready)
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:56.896 UTC [shim] handlePutState -> DEBU 542 [dcd9c8c3]Received RESPONSE. Successfully updated state
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:56.896 UTC [shim] func1 -> DEBU 543 [dcd9c8c3]Transaction completed. Sending COMPLETED
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:56.897 UTC [shim] func1 -> DEBU 544 [dcd9c8c3]Move state message COMPLETED
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:56.897 UTC [shim] handleMessage -> DEBU 545 [dcd9c8c3]Handling ChaincodeMessage of type: COMPLETED(state:ready)
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:56.897 UTC [shim] func1 -> DEBU 546 [dcd9c8c3]send state message COMPLETED
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:56.897 UTC [chaincode] processStream -> DEBU 547 [dcd9c8c3]Received message COMPLETED from shim
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:56.898 UTC [chaincode] HandleMessage -> DEBU 548 [dcd9c8c3]Fabric side Handling ChaincodeMessage of type: COMPLETED in state ready
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:56.898 UTC [chaincode] HandleMessage -> DEBU 549 [dcd9c8c334467ee867fdd82fdbbec483532281364b20fda1fcd1298a66a836b3]HandleMessage- COMPLETED. Notify
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:56.898 UTC [chaincode] notify -> DEBU 54a notifying Txid:dcd9c8c334467ee867fdd82fdbbec483532281364b20fda1fcd1298a66a836b3
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:56.898 UTC [chaincode] Execute -> DEBU 54b Exit
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:56.898 UTC [ccprovider] NewCCContext -> DEBU 54c NewCCCC (chain=advertiseragencychannel,chaincode=mycc,version=1.0,txid=dcd9c8c334467ee867fdd82fdbbec483532281364b20fda1fcd1298a66a836b3,syscc=false,proposal=0xc421a6b310,canname=mycc:1.0
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:56.899 UTC [chaincode] Launch -> DEBU 54d launchAndWaitForRegister fetched 1183 bytes from file system
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:56.899 UTC [chaincode] launchAndWaitForRegister -> DEBU 54e chaincode mycc:1.0 is being launched
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:56.899 UTC [chaincode] getArgsAndEnv -> DEBU 54f Executable is chaincode
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:56.899 UTC [chaincode] getArgsAndEnv -> DEBU 550 Args [chaincode -peer.address=peer0.org1:7051]
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:56.900 UTC [chaincode] launchAndWaitForRegister -> DEBU 551 start container: mycc:1.0(networkid:dev,peerid:peer0.org1.com)
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:56.900 UTC [chaincode] launchAndWaitForRegister -> DEBU 552 start container with args: chaincode -peer.address=peer0.org1:7051
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:56.900 UTC [chaincode] launchAndWaitForRegister -> DEBU 553 start container with env:
peer0.org1.com    |     CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc:1.0
peer0.org1.com    |     CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
peer0.org1.com    |     CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
peer0.org1.com    |     CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_SHIM=warning
peer0.org1.com    |     CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_FORMAT=%{color}%{time:2006-01-02 15:04:05.000 MST} [%{module}] %{shortfunc} -> %{level:.4s} %{id:03x}%{color:reset} %{message}
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:56.901 UTC [container] lockContainer -> DEBU 554 waiting for container(dev-peer0.org1.com-mycc-1.0) lock
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:56.901 UTC [container] lockContainer -> DEBU 555 got container (dev-peer0.org1.com-mycc-1.0) lock
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:56.903 UTC [dockercontroller] Start -> DEBU 556 Cleanup container dev-peer0.org1.com-mycc-1.0
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:56.904 UTC [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 557 Stop container dev-peer0.org1.com-mycc-1.0(No such container: dev-peer0.org1.com-mycc-1.0)
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:56.910 UTC [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 558 Kill container dev-peer0.org1.com-mycc-1.0 (No such container: dev-peer0.org1.com-mycc-1.0)
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:56.912 UTC [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 559 Remove container dev-peer0.org1.com-mycc-1.0 (No such container: dev-peer0.org1.com-mycc-1.0)
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:56.912 UTC [dockercontroller] Start -> DEBU 55a Start container dev-peer0.org1.com-mycc-1.0
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:56.912 UTC [dockercontroller] createContainer -> DEBU 55b Create container: dev-peer0.org1.com-mycc-1.0
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:57.043 UTC [dockercontroller] createContainer -> DEBU 55c Created container: dev-peer0.org1.com-mycc-1.0-fb6be780039642ab28b06bc02e8e4cad69b480256333e2b3fc8a7877a9ffdf1d
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:57.528 UTC [dockercontroller] Start -> DEBU 55d Started container dev-peer0.org1.com-mycc-1.0
peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:57.528 UTC [container] unlockContainer -> DEBU 55e container lock deleted(dev-peer0.org1.com-mycc-1.0)
```

The only thing I can think of is that my network in composer is called "consortium_poc" and this is using a network id that looks different - it appears to be "dev" but I'm not even sure if they are the same thing. My peers are using the `CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=consortium_poc` env variable.

I've tried any number of combinations of parameters on the instantiate call.

I'm nearly all the way there. This last little step is driving me nuts.
Any hints or pointers?

**EDIT**: A little more google had me add this parameter to the peers

```
CORE_PEER_NETWORKID=consortium_poc
```

Now it looks like the networkid value is correct, but it still all stops at the "unlock container" message just as before.

**Edit2:**

So with a little more try things and see what it does it now uses IP addresses in the call described as problematic below:

```
2017-10-30 15:52:33.553 UTC [chaincode] launchAndWaitForRegister -> DEBU 8cc start container with args: chaincode -peer.address=172.24.0.6:7051
```

The container it tried to create says the following:

```
Error starting SimpleAsset chaincode: Error trying to connect to local peer: x509: cannot validate certificate for 172.24.0.6 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
```

I changed only two things:

1. Added `CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true` to the peers
2. Added back `CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock` to the orderer

2.

Comment: Are you using node sdk or command line?

Comment: peer0.org1.com    | 2017-10-28 02:02:56.899 UTC [chaincode] getArgsAndEnv -> DEBU 550 Args [chaincode -peer.address=peer0.org1:7051]

The line above looks suspicious - as peer.address=peer0.org1:7051 should be peer.address=peer0.org1.com:7051

Can you check your compose file / environment variables and make sure that peer0.org1 does not appear in your config?  And if it does, change it to peer0.org1.com.  It's likely the CORE_PEER_ADDRESS variable which is not set correctly

Comment: Command line. 

CORE_PEER_ADDRESS is correctly set - I can see it in my CLI logs.

This (whatever this is) in that getArgsAndEnv call is stripping off the .com. 

When I look at the log for the actual container it's trying to launch I get: 2017-10-30 15:32:31.889 UTC [shim] userChaincodeStreamGetter -> ERRO 001 Error trying to connect to local peer: context deadline exceeded

Comment: See edit2 above for an update

Comment: You won't be able to use IP addresses and TLS together if you generate things with cryptogen since it only uses DNS names in the SAN field of the certificates.

Comment: Where are you running this?

Comment: Local. 
Adding CORE_PEER_SERVERHOSTOVERRIDE=peer.... for all the peers seems to have fixed the IP issue, but I'm still unable to get the chaincode to instantiate. Same timeout message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key seems to be to have another parameter - `CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS` set in the peers.

For future reference for anyone else struggling with this I'll provide a set of config that works for my use case. Remember this is for 4 orgs - here I edited to Org1.com - Org4.com with two peers each and an orderer at Orderer.com.

If anyone with more familiarity with this stuff can comment on any of the properties that are duplicated or superfluous then I'm all ears. This took a lot longer than I'd have hoped to get working - I'm clearly no fabric expert...

peer-base

```
services:
  peer-base:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_poc
      - CORE_PEER_NETWORKID=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_poc
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=true
      - CORE_PEER_EXTERNALENDPOINT=true
      - CORE_PEER_ENDORSER_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/chaincode
    command: peer node start --peer-defaultchain=false
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/chaincode/
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/mofabric/peer/crypto
        - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/mofabric/peer/channel-artifacts
```

orderer

```
  orderer:
    container_name: orderer
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer
    networks:
        poc:
            aliases:
              - ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}

    environment:
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_poc
      - CORE_PEER_NETWORKID=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_poc
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - GRPC_TRACE=all=true,
      - GRPC_VERBOSITY=debug
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7050
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISPROFILE=Genesis
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/orderer/genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true 
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/etc/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/etc/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/etc/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt ]
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/
    command: orderer
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/
      - ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/etc/hyperledger/orderer/genesis.block
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/:/etc/hyperledger/peers/
      - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/orderer.com/orderers/orderer.orderer.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/orderer.com/orderers/orderer.orderer.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/orderer/tls
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
```

cli

```
  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=peer0.org1.com:7052
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_poc
      - CORE_PEER_NETWORKID=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_poc
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - GRPC_TRACE=all=true,
      - GRPC_VERBOSITY=debug
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_SERVERHOSTOVERRIDE=peer0.org1.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/mofabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.com/users/Admin@mediaocean.com/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/chaincode
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/chaincode
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/mofabric/peer/crypto
        - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/mofabric/peer/channel-artifacts
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/users
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.com/peers/peer0.org1.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.com/peers/peer0.org1.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - ./crypto-config:/crypto-config
        - ./channel-artifacts:/channel-artifacts
        - ./scripts:/scripts/
    depends_on:
      - orderer
      - peer0.org1.com
      - peer1.org1.com
      - peer0.org2.com
      - peer1.org2.com
      - peer0.org3.com
      - peer1.org3.com
      - peer0.org4.com
      - peer1.org4.com
    networks:
        poc:
            aliases:
              - ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}
```

So just as a final list of things I did - again as a sanity check:

```
generate genesis block
generate channel
generate anchor peers

start fabric

in cli:
create channel
have all peers join channel (the byfn script shows how).
update anchor peers (byfn again).

have org1 in channel package, then orgs 2-4 serially sign chaincode (the chaincode for operators document describes this).

install chaincode on all peers.
instantiate it on peer0.org1.com
```

This may not be perfect (or even close to being correct) but it has finally worked.